# Using jinja inside jinja

Tags: html, jinja2

Here's what I want to do:

```
{% for disaster in disasters %}
    <a href="{% url {{disaster.link}} %}">{{disaster.name}}</a>
```

When I try to open the HTML page I get:
Error during template rendering

With exception value as:
Exception Value:
Reverse for '{{disaster.link}}' not found. '{{disaster.link}}' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

How can I do the same task with or without jinja logic?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the curly braces around disaster.link?  I've only worked with Jinja once, but that stood out to me.